# Access to image library

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

In EA we've got image library where can I add image and later I can use on picture control on diagram. I was wonder how to add image to this library from EA Addin and open image from library. I can't find anything in API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the API AFAIR.
You'll probably have to query the database.
Check the table t_image. You can read the db using Repository.SQLQuery(SqlString), and you can insert a new record in t_image using Repository.Execute(SQLInsertString)